# How to detect a string that starts with 'abc' and then has 'n' numbers and then again has alphabets?

Tags: r, regex

I have a bunch of strings:

```
x<-c('abc13faifnaisnf'
,'abc134ivjndnva'
,'abc2133knvknanv'
,'abc123214isdjvdnvsdnv'
,'abc9nakcnq'
,'abcdjodjsojaca'
,'abc102ei1e11e1'
,'aacqdqjofjo211e'
,'abc1232414141242jf12132')
```

I need a method that helps me detect strings that start with abc then have numbers and then only alphabets.

In the above case I would want the output to be: TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

How do I write a regex(or any other method) to detect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the pattern `abc` at the start (`^`) of the string, followed by one or more digits (`[0-9]+`) and then one or more letters (`[[:alpha:]]+`) until the end (`$`) of the string

```
grepl("^abc[0-9]+[[:alpha:]]+$", x)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

#### data

```
x <- c("abc13faifnaisnf", "abc134ivjndnva", "abc2133knvknanv", 
   "abc123214isdjvdnvsdnv", "abc9nakcnq", "abcdjodjsojaca", 
   "abc102ei1e11e1", "aacqdqjofjo211e", "abc1232414141242jf12132")
```

Answer (score 0):

`"^abc[0-9]+[A-z]+$"` should do what you want.